# Create temp table with column names from another tables column data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to create a temp table with columns named with data from a single column in another table for example -

```
singleColumn
-data1
-data2
-data3
-data4
```

then from this create a temp table like -

```
data1 | data2 | data3 | data4
```

edit:

I have a user that can have 0 to whatever demographics from the demographics table. A join will return several rows for a user. I need this data joined on 1 row so I can store this data in CSV file.

Comment: Yes. But what will you do about types?

Comment: @stuartainsworth all will be nvarchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think its possible to return data the way I would like so ended up doing doing it with 2 DataTables.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @dynamicSql varchar(1000)
set @dynamicSql = 'create table #yourTempTable ('

select @dynamicSql += yourDataCol + ' nvarchar(100) not null, '
from TestTempTables

set @dynamicSql = LEFT(@dynamicSql, len(@dynamicSql) - 1) + ')'

exec(@dynamicSql)
```

Comment: The amount of columns count is going to be random. Could be 5 or 10 or 15. How can I handle that?

Comment: How random?  If you want the top 5 you could have a `select top 5 ...`.  You'd have to order the query accordingly, though.  Can you specify when/how/what you want to select from that column?

Comment: well different users belong to different companies and depending on how there company set up the demographics. So a company could choose to do 10 demographics for that user and another company could do 20. But in the end I need the results returned as 1 row instead of many so I can save results to a csv file. Its either that or I will do it in the c# code