# Convert 900 Tables in Access to a CSV file

Tags: sql, csv, ms-access, vba

I have an existing process that uses Access as a recipe manager and would like to convert it into a CSV that will work with WonderWare's built-in recipe manager. The access file has 900 tables, each table has 8 fields. The two that I am concerned with are called MachineTag and RecipeValue. I would like to convert these existing tables over to a CSV (I will use excel terms, to explain): Column A will have all of the possible MachineTags. Row 1 will have the name of the recipe (which is the name of the table in the existing access database).

Sample table from Access:

[image: Example from Access]

Sample of the CSV file:

[image: CSV sample]

Hopefully that explains what I am trying to achieve. I have one table in access that is called MasterTag, that specifies all the MachineTag possibilities. If a Recipe doesn't have that tag, it's fine if it puts a zero in that field. The number of records per table in access ranges from 800 to 1200. (MasterTag, has the reference copy with all 1200 possible Tags.) The code I have thus far is producing SQL statements using Debut.Print, that I can then copy and paste in SQL in access and it will work. I just don't know how to put it all together.

```
Sub GoMomma()
    Dim db As DAO.Database, 
        tb As DAO.TableDef

    Set db = CurrentDb()

    For Each tb In db.TableDefs
        If Left$(tb.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
            strSQL = "SELECT [MasterTag].MachineTag As TagName, [" & tb.Name & "].RecipeValue " & _
                     "FROM " & tb.Name & "INNER JOIN MasterTag ON ([" & tb.Name & "].MachineTag = [MasterTag].MachineTag)"
            Debug.Print strSQL
        End If
    Next tb
End Sub
```

I have tried various recordset and FreeFile() print, saving to a txt/csv, but the problem with the freefile method is that it will just append at the end, instead of having each one be a row. I have made zero progress over 4+ hours using the recordset method. I have tried creating a new tblTemp, just to use on the fly if needed, but no luck. I don't have code samples from everything. I got frustrated at one point and shutdown my laptop and lost some of the work. But really it was just junk anyways.

**EDIT:**
I thought of a bullet proof way to do this, but haven't looked at the coding side of it yet, just conceptually it seems solid. I can make an excel spreadsheet with the top row filled in with the table names and first column with the MachineTags. In the access vba I would get the current table name and machine tag name and search through the spreadsheet and find out what cell it needs to insert the RecipeValue (example: B5), then it would move onto the next MachineTag in that table (if MachineTag not found, insert new row, with new MachineTag), when that table is complete, move onto next one (the table names, will all be there, so I shouldn't need to check and/or do an insert of a new column). Kind of worked out on my screenshots from above:

[image: Bulletproof idea]

Once everything is done I can save/convert the spreadsheet into a CSV and I'll be done. Pretty busy on Tuesday, so might not get to work on this until Wed, but it seems like a viable path forward, in my mind at least. [For my own records, possible solution / right direction, reminder to take a look at this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450512/how-to-find-cell-value-based-on-row-and-column-id-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close.  Perhaps this will help: create a temp table, then loop through all of the other tables and insert records into the temp table.  Then you can export the temp table as a csv file.  Here is some sample code, based on what you have so far.  I left out the MasterTag table to keep the code simpler (and it might not be needed).

```
Sub GoMomma()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tb As DAO.TableDef
    Dim strSQL As String

    Set db = CurrentDb()

    ' drop the temp table if it exists
    For Each tb In db.TableDefs
        If tb.Name = "recipe_temp" Then
            db.Execute "drop table recipe_temp"
        End If
    Next tb

    db.Execute "create table recipe_temp (RecipeName Text, MachineTag Text, RecipeValue Number)"

    For Each tb In db.TableDefs
        If Left$(tb.Name, 4) <> "MSys" And tb.Name <> "recipe_temp" Then
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO recipe_temp (RecipeName, MachineTag, RecipeValue) " & _
                     "SELECT """ & tb.Name & """ as RecipeName, MachineTag, RecipeValue " & _
                     "FROM " & tb.Name
            db.Execute strSQL
        End If
    Next tb

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. That works as you'd expect it to, but it's not exactly what I was hoping for. It outputs everything to the new fields in the table we created, appending everything on top of each other. I was hoping that each field would be named after the table name. In my csv above, B1, C1, D1 are existing table names.

Comment: I saw a similar question here (in regards to part of my scenario): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116072/create-temp-table-with-column-names-from-another-tables-column-data

Comment: More research tells me that the limit for columns / fields in access is 255, so my 900 tables won't be able to be saved to a table, even if I figured out how to do the above. I may look at some old log parser code I have and see if this is anything it might can handle. This is definitely not a simple piece of code.